# Subquery returns more than 1 row in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I had two tables, orderdetails and orders.

I would like to print orderDate, the status of the order & the total price.

In the orderdetails table, there is orderNumber, quantityOrdered, priceEach & productCode.

In the orders, there is status & orderNumber.

I have tried this code but it will not work.

```
SELECT orderDate, status,  (SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) AS prices FROM orderdetails GROUP BY orderNumber)

FROM orders o, orderdetails od

WHERE od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
```

Comment: in which table is the date?

Comment: @KiranShakya I'm thinking now that his data might not be normalized.

Comment: @KiranShakya the date is within the orders table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT t1.orderDate,
       t1.status,
       t2.prices
FROM orders t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT orderNumber,
           SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) AS prices
    FROM orderdetails
    GROUP BY orderNumber
) t2
    ON t1.orderNumber = t2.orderNumber
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is reasonable.  But it should look like this:

```
SELECT o.orderDate, o.status,
       (SELECT SUM(od.quantityOrdered * od.priceEach)
        FROM orderdetails ol
        WHERE od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
       ) as Prices
FROM orders o;
```

This is called a *correlated subquery*.  Note the `WHERE` clause instead of the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a simple join like below,

```
SELECT
    o.date AS order_date,
    o.status AS order_status,
    SUM(od.quanityordered * od.price) AS total_price
FROM orderdetails od
INNER JOIN order o
ON o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
GROUP BY order_date, order_status
```